# unable to save data to postgres database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to make an authentication app with Django and postgres as the database...
I am using function based views.

below is user sign up view in "views.py"

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import UserProfile



def signUpUser(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    email = request.POST["email"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    u = UserProfile(name=username, email=email, password=password)
    u.save()
```

and below is the user model in "models.py"

```
from django.db import models


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

below is the template

```
         <form method="POST">
             {% csrf_token %}
            <h1>Create Account</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
               <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
               <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
               <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>or use your email for registration</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
         </form>
```

I don't know where I am going wrong, after pressing the submit button I get code 200, and I can't see any errors in the console, so, I have no idea where the bug is.

this is what I see in the console after pressing the submit button.

```
[20/Jul/2022 20:25:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2754
```

Comment: you must Do some changes because You changed the User Model ... Let me know if You want or not and I will Answer ...

Comment: @Ayman How do I make the changes?

Comment: 1) This `def signUpUser()` seems to be missing code. I don't see a `return` , lack of which would throw an error. Include the complete code for the view. 2) Is the data showing up in the database table? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: - @AdrianKlaver
what should I return?

Comment: I would go through the [Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/).